# Date archive permalinks for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, archives, date

Is it possible to have date based permalinks for a custom taxonomy?

ie http://www.blah.com/taxonomy/taxonomy-term/2011/08/08

TIA!
d.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

/2011/08/?taxonomy=term

I'm not sure how to create a rewrite rule though to make it "pretty"